# Check network availability using phone's modem (low level)

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, gsm

I am trying to find network availability using my phone's GSM modem. Last night I had almost done it using following procedure with `adb shell` connecting phone with Ubuntu laptop.

Terminal 1

```
./adb shell
su
cat /dev/smd0
```

Terminal 2

```
./adb shell
su
echo -e "AT+CIND?\r" > /dev/smd0
```

In Terminal 1 I had `CIND 4 4 1 x x x` output and I figured it's 3rd digit which is either 1 or 0 depending on network is available or not. Now today after factory resetting my phone, I can't reproduce this result.

What could be wrong? I have already tried ttySMD0, ttyGS0, ttyUSB0 etc.